# Unity: Receive Firebase Short Dynamic Link in DynamicLinkReceived callback event

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I would like to use **Firebase Dynamic Links for Unity (Android/iOS)** so users can invite friends and be rewarded with.
Each user gets a different Short Dynamic Link in the form of **https://test.page.link/abcd**
The user can share this Short DynamicLink with friends.

*When the invited friend comes into the app, this callback is called.*

```
private void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
        Debug.LogFormat("Received dynamic link {0}",
                        dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString);
    }
```

*Unfortunately, I only get back the base link that was necessary to create the short dynamic link.*

> Received dynamic link https://www.example.com/referral?xxxxxxxxxx

*I get an additional native output in my iOS app:*

> IOSNative::Native->Unity callback data:
> {"m_EventName":"continueUserActivity","m_Data":"https://test.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/referral?xxxxxxxxxx&apn=de.test.testapp&isi=123456789&ibi=de.test.testapp&cid=1579347010984123886&_osl=https://test.page.link/abcd&_fpb=AB6327276CFGHT==&_cpt=cpit&_iumenbl=1&_iumchkactval=1&_plt=2076&_uit=2692&_cpb=1"}
> 2020-01-14 15:30:20.455009+0100 ambassador[315:8406]
> IOSNative::Native->Unity callback data:
> {"m_EventName":"applicationDidBecomeActive","m_Data":""}

**Now my question is how do I get the generated short dynamic link that I have shared with a friend in OnDynamicLink callback( https://test.page.link/abcd)?**

I need the value behind the parameter "&_osl" as seen in additional native output. But I only get the Base Url back in Unity (https://www.example.com/referral?xxxxxxxxxx).

Comment: I really want to know that too, the docs does not helps because has little information.

Comment: @TiagoP.O. I have solved it this way see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution at the end was to shorten the BaseLink with the help of DynamicLinks.GetShortLinkAsync.

```
            //unescape url
        baseLink = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.UnEscapeURL(baseLink);

        var components = new DynamicLinkComponents(
        // The base Link.
        new Uri(baseLink),
        // The dynamic link URI prefix.
        domainUriPrefix) {
            IOSParameters = new IOSParameters(PackageName) {
                AppStoreId = "XXXXXXXXX"
            },
            AndroidParameters = new AndroidParameters(PackeName)
        };

        string inviteLink = string.Empty;

        await DynamicLinks.GetShortLinkAsync(components, options).ContinueWith((task) => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError("GetShortLinkAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.LogError("GetShortLinkAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            // Short Link has been created.
            inviteLink = task.Result.Url.ToString();
        });
```